# module' object has no attribute 'VideoWriter_fourcc' opencv python 2.7 opencv 2.4.13

Tags: python, opencv, module, video-capture

I am having an interesting issue with OpenCV. I am trying to save a video but when I run this script I get the error "'module' object has no attribute VideoWriter_fourcc. I am 99% positive the attributedoes exist and every tutorial (including OpenCV documentation) says its a thing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
def SaveVideo():
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#define video object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret == True):
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        #write flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if (cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Yea just discovered that was the issue thanks so much!

Comment: I googled your error message, found and verified in 30 secs the issue (thankfully you had Python 2 in question title). It's your best starting point for these things :)